# Pointer to Vector Memory Loss

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector, heap-memory

I have come against a problem with my pointer vectors...
And i got an idea what the problem might be:

When I create a pointer to a vector, the pointer reserves the size of the vector on the heap. So that basicly means, that the pointer now points to the memory of the vector without anything inside... When i now resize or pushback the vector, will the pointer now still point to the whole memory of the vector or just the memory which has been allocated at the beginning?

I also want to know, if there are some tricks you can do to fix that (if what i think is true). Is the "vector.reserve(n)" a method of accomplishing this? Or is there something i could do to overwrite the pointers memory adress, to a vector after it has been initialised?

Comment: How is this a "memory loss"?

Comment: Do you really need a pointer to a vector that's on the heap? It is extremely unlikely that you do.

Comment: Do you really mean "pointer to a vector" or do you mean "pointer to the first element in a vector"? Perhaps show some code.

Comment: I don't want to obverwhelm anyone with code so i put it like this: I have a pointer = new vector<object> and then i pushed the objects into this vector. The Object has a function which returns a character that i set when initialising the objects. Now when i try to read out that vector i get a lot of weird characters. So i thought, that the length of the pointer didn't resize as well, so he is now picking trying to read out whats beyond the vectors range.

Comment: @RIJIK: Then that code is broken. We can't help you without seeing it. Of course now that would be a totally different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector is class that has internal pointer to vector's elements using continuous block of memory in the heap. Long enough for all reserved vector's elements (capacity() method)
So, if you create vector (in local scope's stack OR in the heap - doesn't matter) it creates this layout

```
[ vector   [ ptr-to-data ] ] --> HEAP: [ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]

vector<int> v1(3); // whole vector instance in the stack 
vector<int> *pv2 = new vector<int>(3); // pointer to vector in the heap
```

each of these 2 vector instances has its pointer to its elements in the heap as well

Vector manages its pointer to the data internally.
When you push_back() more elements than its current .capacty() it will re-allocate new continuous block of memory and copy-construct or move all old elements to this new block.

Comment: So the vector has all its memory on the heap already?! That means, that i can make it a lot bigger then the array without making a pointer to it right? I have written my problem in the comment of my question, can you tell me whats wrong in my case?

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR ANSWERS! It gave me the knowledge i need to fix my problem! For those interested in knowing what i did wrong : Since the Vector repositions all its memory when getting resized (since he is using pointers --> kinda what i suspected at the beginning), i shouldn't have assigned pointers to its elements. The vector is like something that moves through the heap, so pointers, which point to its elements have to be reassigned whenever the vector is being resized(moves) again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, rather than what you claimed in your question, you had pointers to _elements_. Totally different.

Comment: I don't want to kill you with pages of code, so i am trying to get only the main aspects. Maybe it was too short. I am sorry

Comment: @RIJIK yes, you understood everything correctly: you cannot store pointers to vector's elements. because vector's internal array (block of heap memory) can (and usually will) be moved on resizing event

Answer (score 5):

> "When I create a pointer to a vector, the pointer reserves the size of the vector on the heap.

*No, it doesn't!* When you create a pointer to a vector, you have a pointer. Nothing more. It doesn't point to anything yet, and it certainly hasn't reserved any "heap memory" for you.

You still need to actually create the vector that will be pointed-to.

```
std::vector<int>* ptr1;                            // just a pointer;
ptr1 = new std::vector<int>();                     // there we go;
delete ptr1;                                       // don't forget this;

auto ptr2 = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();  // alternatively...
```

Y'know, it's very rare that you need to dynamically-allocate a container. Usually you just want to construct it in the usual fashion:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

That's it. No need for pointers.

---

> When i now resize or pushback the vector, will the pointer now still point to the whole memory of the vector or just the memory which has been allocated at the beginning?

Regardless of how you constructed/allocated it, the vector itself never moves spontaneously (only the dynamic memory that it is managing for you internally), so you do not need to worry about this.

---

> I also want to know, if there are some tricks you can do to fix that

No need, as there's nothing to fix.

---

> Is the "vector.reserve(n)" a method of accomplishing this?

Theoretically, if this *were* a problem (which it isn't) then, yes, this could possibly form the basis of a solution.